# How to know if an object is in a list of objects in python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of Information objects:

```
list_users = [Information(name='Robert',  age=29), 
              Information(name='Richard', age=33),  
              Information(name='Carol',   age=43),  
              Information(name='Ann',     age=24)]
```

What is the easier way to know if a specific person is in the list based on his name?

I've been thinking if we could create magic methods but using lists in this way:

`Robert in list_users: True`

If is this impossible, someone could give me another idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use for `any` and a generator expression.

```
if any(x.name == "Robert" for x in list_users):
    print("Robert is in the list")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access name from the information object using `obj.name`

```
for user in list_users:
    if user.name = 'Robert':
        print("yes")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
next((x for x in test_list if x.value == value), None)
```

This gets the first item from the list that matches the condition, and returns None if no item matches. It's my preferred single-expression form.

However,

```
for x in test_list:
    if x.value == value:
        print("i found it!")
        break
```

The naive loop-break version, is perfectly Pythonic -- it's concise, clear, and efficient. To make it match the behavior of the one-liner:

```
for x in test_list:
    if x.value == value:
        print("i found it!")
        break
else:
    x = None
```

This will assign None to x if you don't break out of the loop.